# Using 'Cost' field in product attributes

Tags: nopcommerce

My issue is: I'd like to take advantage of the "Cost" field within a product attribute value, and have the price adjustment applied and go to the cart instead of the product price.

I'm able to access attribute.Cost, and display it within _ProductAttributes, but when that option is selected, and Add To Cart is clicked, it is applying the price adjustment value to the product price, not the cost in the attribute.

I was able to get around this for now by bringing the product cost into the ProductAttributeModel, and displaying that, just for correctness, but then I'm stuck having 1 original price, with multiple discount options.

What I want is to be able to have original (attribute.cost) and price adjustment both go to the cart. This will allow me to have multiple original values, with their associated price adjustments.

How can I accomplish this? Am I just missing enabling a setting in the admin backend? I'm very close!